# React-Boostrap - Fix Row at bottom

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, react-bootstrap

I am using React, TypeScript and React-Boostrap.
I am currently trying to fix a `<Row/>` at the bottom but nothing works:

**Rendering:**

```
render() {
    return (
        <Container id={"chat"} className={`${style.chatroom}`}>
            <Row>
                <Col xl lg md sm={12}>
                    <h1 className={`${style.title}`}>Channel by Emixam23</h1>
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Col xl lg md sm={12}>
                    <h5 className={`${style.logged_user_id}`}>{this.props[STORE_LOGGED_USER].getLoggedUser.id}</h5>
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Col xl lg md sm={12}>
                    <ChatChannelMessagesList messages={this.getMessages()}/>
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row className={"fixed-row-bottom"}>
                <Col xl lg md sm={12}>
                    <ChatChannelInput onSendClicked={(input: string) => this.sendMessage(input)}/>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

**style.css**:

```
.chatroom {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.title {
    background-color: #620000;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.logged_user_id {
    background-color: #620000;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.fixed-row-bottom {
    position:fixed !important;
    bottom:0 !important;
}
```

Any idea? I am not really a CSS expert, maybe I am missing something I don't know... Thanks for any help !

Comment: you want to implement a footer, right?

Comment: Nop, chat input :/ This is the right column of my chat app (thinkin about whatsapp, imessage, etc)

Comment: possible to show a working snippet, so we can play around with it. And also image representation of the requirement.

Comment: How do you do this?

Comment: I'm trying to create a working demo, give me some time please.

Comment: @Emixam23 this might help get you started http://jsfiddle.net/ramnathv/kd7Lwgy3/2/

Comment: The issue is that it's a `create-react-app`, how do you want me to put it in the playground?

Comment: Ok, so I created the environment, make this look exactly like what you have in your code. And also on a paper of draw.io, upload an image of what you need as your final product. https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/KKPxYdz?editors=0110

Comment: Alright, firstly, thanks. It works on your environment but not on mine.. I really do not get what's currently happening.. So I will update the code with the full container (page) code I have: https://codepen.io/Emixam23/pen/RwbYmxG?editors=0111

Answer (score 1):

try using

```css
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 